# Using angular-google-maps can't bind click event to a markers for displaying single window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm receiving a JSON object as Data source for my markers. After that I'm binding Click/Close functions for each marker

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/A9IbIFpj3d9tH6z9NYjf?p=preview

```
    angular.forEach(tmp, function(value, key){
        
        value.onClick = function(){
            console.log("Clicked!");
            $scope.selected.show = false;
            $scope.selected = value;
            $scope.selected.show = !$scope.selected.show;
            $scope.$apply();
                            
        };
        value.CloseClick = function() {
            $scope.selected.show = false;
            console.log("CloseClicked");
            $scope.$apply();
        };
        this.push(value);
    }, $scope.markers);
```

and then drawing markers on a Google Map using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps)

```
            <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
                <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" fit="true" coords="'self'" click="onClick">
                </ui-gmap-markers>
                <ui-gmap-window coords="selected" show="selected.show" closeClick="closeClick"><div>aga</div></ui-gmap-window>                      
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

but when I click on a marker, the function onClick does not trigger. I'm new in Angular.js, but it seems I have an issue with it (or maybe worse for me - with JavaScript itself), not with Angular Google Maps, but I'm not sure. Thanks for any help.

**[UPDATE]** Problem solved by using `click="'onClick'"` instead of `click="onClick"`

Answer (score 4):

You could also add parentheses () to the methods, e.g. click="onClick()"